# How do i pass 2 values to a view?

Tags: views

I have a Drupal View that displays the 2 most recent articles from our db. How do i allow a user to select which article they would like to display. And, if the user does not choose the 2 articles then the 2 most recent will be shown.

I tried to use filters and the "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it" option. But I cant seem to figure out how this would be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try With Flag Module ?

Comment: No, let me take a look at that!

Comment: Seems like a great module but we would'nt want our users to have to flag content. Our intentions is to use the view's display "page" option to drive a user to a page so that they could choose which articles they would like the view to display.

Comment: How are you loading your view, through an url or as a block? I wondering if you use `views_embed_view()` e.g loading your view programatically?

Comment: How many articles should your user be able to select, 1 or 2? If so, how would you do this? Checkboxs, Autocomplete (by title, by date)? How many articles would would your users be selecting from? If you have hundreds of articles then checkboxes or a multi-choice list might get out of hand.

I know you nixed the flag module, but this is likely the route I would take if I was facing this issue.

Comment: Ultimately i have a sticky footer that is displaying this view of the 2 articles. In theory, i need an end user to be able control what 2 articles are being displayed in this footer to visitors of the site. (ie. Spearate page that allows end-user to control what 2 articles are being displayed.) Would i create another page with form or should i create another "View Display Page" with contextual filter  somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the [argument in via the URL](https://www.drupal.org/node/54455), you can pass multiple args in using '+'. So http://example.com/my-view/[nid1]+[nid2]